# Is there no good way to run the Vienna RNA tools on Windows?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna, software

I'm trying to get the Vienna RNA tools (particularly RNAfold) running locally (as opposed to using the web interface--because I have lots of sequences I wish to process in batch mode). On the website, it mentions that there are pre-compiled versions of the software available for all major operating systems, however the site seems to be down. All that's still accessible is the GitHub page with source code access.

From my experience, trying to get large C/C++ projects, that often have quite a few third party dependencies, to compile is a huge pain. And even the Python "version" (really a Python wrapper around the C++ code) doesn't install with pip, despite having a compiler available (and found by pip), there are quite some header files that aren't on my Windows system that it complains about--and I've generally never had a problem with pip not being able to install other Python packages, even ones that are internally mostly C/C++. Even installing Anaconda, then bioconda, and then trying to install "viennarna", it isn't found. I'm beginning to think that these tools are just broken other than on the sorts of workstations on which they were developed, which already have all the necessary dependencies and headers.

Has anyone else managed to get a local install of these tools working?

Comment: It think this question is ways better fitted for the bioinformatics community: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ Shall I migrate it?

Comment: I can access the website normally, and I have been using precompiled ViennaRNA on Windows without any problems.

Comment: @Chris I didn't know there was a separate bioinformatics community, yes it would be better migrated there.

Answer (score 2):

Against my better nature (I think that this is a question about software, not biology), I offer:

https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#download

[image: Download screenshot]

This download works for me to get the precompiled packages.

You could also try here (for a few days): davidleader.net/Wienershnitzel/index.html

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the irrelevant pieces Domen is responding to.

Comment: And so we are left with the situation that a helpful and correct answer to a question, despite being off-topic, is sitting on -1. And all because I pointed out that most modern bioinformatics is written on and for Unix-type operating systems, which does not include MS Windows but does include another which also has widespread support for consumer software.

Comment: That website gives a time out error for me, and has been doing so all week. In fact all of tbi.univie.ac.at is inaccessible for me, not just /RNA or the download page. I can access the Github no problem since it's a separate site but the download links from there only lead back to that site.

If it works for you, then it must be an internet problem outside the site itself.

Comment: @biohacker I can also access the page. Unsure what the issue is on your end, I am looking on Firefox. Possibly switch browsers? If the download were smaller, I would simply link you to a version hosted elsewhere.

Comment: @biohacker I was using Safari on the Mac, which sometimes has trouble because of Chromocentric websites. Where are you trying to access from? North Korea? I’m in Britain.

Comment: @biohacker I wonder if you're on a network where someone has a bit over-aggressively limited which URLs are accessible, perhaps assuming that domains that are not ".com", ".edu", etc, must be hosting sketchy sites.

Comment: I'm on Chrome, in the United States. I can access univie.ac.at (which takes me to the main university home page) but not tbi.univie.ac.at. I will try accessing from other locations, but I believe I've tried also at home (where I'm not behind any sort of filter) instead of at work without success. I did manage to find Ivo Hofacker's faculty page by searching starting from the main university homepage, but it doesn't seem to have a link to the software.

Comment: @biohacker — I'll download again and mount it on a webpage for download.

Comment: @biohacker Try https://davidleader.net/Wienershnitzel/index.html

Comment: @David Thanks for that!

Comment: Another few options: run Vienna on a virtual machine with a (totally free) installation of linux - basic ones like Ubuntu or Mint are very easy to install. Run on a Linux distro designed to run from USB drives - Puppy linux used to be the goto there, dual boot a linux distro, or (best IMO) run one of the several docker containers for viennaRNA .